# SQL - aggregate function to get value from same row as MAX()

Tags: sql-server-2005, group-by, max

I have one table with columns channel, value and timestamp, and another table with 7 other columns with various data.

I'm joining these two together, and I want to select the maximum value of the value column within an hour, and the timestamp of the corresponding row. This is what I've tried, but it (obviously) doesn't work.

```
SELECT
    v.channel,
    MAX(v.value),
    v.timestamp,
    i.stuff,
    ...
FROM
    Values v
INNER JOIN
    @Information i
ON i.type = v.type
GROUP BY channel, DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp), i.stuff, ...
```

I'm (not very surprisingly) getting the following error:

> "dbo.Values.timestamp" is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

How should I do this correctly?

Comment: Select `DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp)` instead?

Comment: @Amber, unfortunately, I need the exact time, not just the hour part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)() or [DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)() features to get the results as appropriate. Something like:

```
;WITH RankedResults AS
(
    SELECT
        channel,
        value,
        timestamp,
        type,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(hour,timestamp) ORDER BY value desc) as Position
    FROM
        Values
)
SELECT
   v.channel,
   v.value,
   v.timestamp,
   i.stuff
   /* other columns */
FROM
   RankedResults v
       inner join
   @Information i
       on
           v.type = i.type
WHERE
   v.Position = 1
```

(whether to use RANK or DENSE_RANK depends on what you want to do in the case of ties, really)

(Edited the SQL to include the join, in response to Tomas' comment)

Comment: Although I did overthink it - ties for first place always get position 1, so RANK and DENSE_RANK are exactly equivalent in this case - if you need to eliminate ties, you'll have to add more descriminating columns in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: In which of the select statements should I do the join?

Comment: Hm... I just realized this isn't doing exactly what I intended. Instead of giving me the max value for each distinct set of other properties (instrumentType, which I called type in the original post, channel and instrumentId), it gets the *overall* maximum values. How do I make it "group by" these other columns?

Comment: @Tomas - the PARTITION BY clause effectively identifies the groups in which the RANK function is going to determine the positions - so add additional "GROUP BY" columns in there.

Answer (score -1):

you must include 'v.timestamp' in the Group By clause.
Hope this will help for you.